# How to convert JSON news data from API to flutter news blocks in flutter news toolkit

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-frog

I am working with flutter news toolkit. I was able to successfully setup environment for it and everything is working fine as long as I am providing data from in memory data source. But when I want to get data from my own custom source then there is no way to transform that data into flutter news blocks.
Actually I want to server a rich content to my users. But I am not sure how can I achieve this with flutter news toolkit by converting my json into news blocks.